# I am trying to to generate a .sql dump file and auto-download using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a simple form that displays a list of databases on a server, allow the user to select a DB hit ok and it start downloading a .sql file that can be used to restore the DB

```
<?php
ob_start();
// print_r($_POST);
$username = "dbselect"; 
$password = "PASSWORD"; 
$hostname = "SERVER"; 
$dbname   = $_POST['db_select'];



if (isset($_POST['db_select'])) { 
    //echo "file created on " . date('mdy');
    // $command = "mysqldump --add-drop-table --result-file=/var/www/db-dump/${dbname}.sql --host=" . $hostname . " --user=" . $username . " --password=". $password . " " . $dbname;
    $command = "mysqldump --opt --add-drop-table --host=" . $hostname . " --user=" . $username . " --password=" . $password . " " . $dbname;

    system($command);

    file_put_contents("/var/www/db-dump/return");

    $dump = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    // send dump file to the output
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($dbname . "_" . date("Y-m-d_H-i-s").".sql"));
    flush();
    echo $dump;
    exit();
    //echo date('mdy');

} else {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=hostname", username, password);
$dbs = $dbh->query('SHOW DATABASES');
?>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1> Databases</h1>
        <p>on <b>d.uk</b></p>
    </header>

    <section class="databases">
        <p>Select and download any production database from any  app or site.</p>

        <form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <select name="db_select" id="">
                <?php
                    foreach ($dbs as $db) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $db['Database'] . "'>";
                        echo $db['Database'];
                        echo "</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <button type="submit">Download database</button>
        </form>

    </section>

</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

The problem I am running into is that only a blank .sql file is created.  If I change it so that I am just using the mysqldump command, designating a file location for the dump, I get more information in the file, but just part of it:

> ### -- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu (i686)
>
> -- Host: localhost    Database:
>
> ---
>
> -- Server version 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
>
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
>   /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
>   /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
>   /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */; /*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE
>   */; /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */; /*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */; /*!40014 SET
>   @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
>   /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE,
>   SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */; /*!40111 SET
>   @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

The databases are pretty large (around 30MB) so the command does take a little time (about 10-15min) so I was thinking it's a timeout problem. The only thing I could find about upping the time for commands sent by php is set_the_limit but that didn't help.

Comment: You can try with bash command mysqldump and exec in php?

Comment: 30mb mysql database is not pretty large, is it?

Comment: Well I just meant that the file is of decent size, so it takes a little longer for the command to be executed.  If it were just a small db, it wouldn't take much time at all to execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

i'm jusing the following script to create a MySQL dump (mine got to 57MB), maybe you can use it (it's not totally good, like the globals):

```
$dbname = $db_database."-".date("Y-m-d G").'.sql';
$backupfile = $root."files/".$dbname;

function backup_tables($host, $user, $pass, $name, $tables = '*') {
        global $dbname;
        global $backupfile;

        $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
        mysql_select_db($name, $link);

        //get all of the tables
        if ($tables == '*') {
            $tables = array();
            $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                $tables[] = $row[0];
            }
        } else {
            $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',', $tables);
        }

        //cycle through
        foreach ($tables as $table) {
            $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
            $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

            $return .= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';
            $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
            $return .= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

            for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                    $return .= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
                    for ($j = 0; $j < $num_fields; $j++) {
                        $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                        $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n", "\\n", $row[$j]);
                        if (isset($row[$j])) {
                            $return .= '"'.$row[$j].'"';
                        } else {
                            $return .= '""';
                        }
                        if ($j < ($num_fields - 1)) {
                            $return .= ',';
                        }
                    }
                    $return .= ");\n";
                }
            }
            $return .= "\n\n\n";
        }

        //save file
        $handle = fopen($backupfile, 'w+');
        fwrite($handle, $return);
        fclose($handle);
    }
backup_tables('localhost', $db_login, $db_pass, $db_database);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think you can get what you're looking for using:

```
<?php
$password = "PASSWORD"; 
$hostname = "SERVER"; 
$dbname   = $_POST['db_select'];



if (isset($_POST['db_select'])) { 
//echo "file created on " . date('mdy');
// $command = "mysqldump --add-drop-table --result-file=/var/www/db-dump/${dbname}.sql --host=" . $hostname . " --user=" . $username . " --password=". $password . " " . $dbname;
$command = "mysqldump --opt --add-drop-table --host=" . $hostname . " --user=" . $username . " --password=" . $password . " " . $dbname;

   if($result=system($command)){
      $fp=fopen($dbname.'.sql','ab');
      $fwrite($fp,$result);
      $fclose($fp);
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [mysqldump-php](https://github.com/ifsnop/mysqldump-php) found on GitHub.

"This is a php version of Linux's mysqldump in terminal '$ mysqldump -u username -p...', without dependencies, output compression and sane defaults.

Out of the box, MySQLDump-PHP supports backing up table structures, the data itself, views and triggers."